# Unable to resolve the value for property 'CosmosDBAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting' but it is added in application settings

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb

I'm having this issue which seems straightforward to solve and so I have fixed with the info I found in SO and the MS docs, but still no luck. The same issue occurs in my dev environment and after deploying in Azure cloud.

I have a function bound to a cosmosDB instance as shown below:

```
{
  "scriptFile" : "../my-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
  "entryPoint" : "com.my.package.MyController.functionToCall",
  "bindings" : [ {
    "type" : "httpTrigger",
    "direction" : "in",
    "name" : "req",
    "route" : "FunctionToCall",
    "methods" : [ "GET" ],
    "authLevel" : "ANONYMOUS"
  }, {
    "type" : "cosmosDB",
    "direction" : "in",
    "name" : "functionToCall",
    "databaseName" : "myproject-db",
    "partitionKey" : "{Query.id}",
    "connectionStringSetting" : "AccountEndpoint=https://cosmosDBAccountName.documents.azure.com:443/; AccountKey=PrimaryKeyFromCosmosDBSettings==;",
    "id" : "{Query.id}",
    "collectionName" : "ObjectToReturn"
  }, {
    "type" : "http",
    "direction" : "out",
    "name" : "$return"
  } ]
}

@CosmosDBInput(name = "name",
                    databaseName = "myproject-db",
                    collectionName = "ObjectToReturn",
                    id = "{Query.id}",
                    partitionKey = "{Query.id}",
                    connectionStringSetting = HARDCODEDFINALSTATICVAR)

private static final HARDCODEDFINALSTATICVAR = "AccountEndpoint=https://cosmosDBAccountName.documents.azure.com:443/; AccountKey=PrimaryKeyFromCosmosDBSettings==;"
```

I have added CosmosDBAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting to my application setting as CosmosDBAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting and ConnectionStringSetting and with values as shown above, plus trying to remove the slash after the port number, plus trying to add a whitespace betwwen URL and the key, plus saving it as Connection String instead of application setting... No luck so far. I'm still getting the 500 HTTP error in telemetry.

I'm starting to suspect that as I created the project from zero and the folder that is deployed in azure from Azure devops via a release pipeline and I didn't add a local.setting file so far, it could be related. My understanding is that the local.setting.json file is only useful for local deployment. On that regard I installed the azure core extensions via npm and func install extension and locally it creates a set ob files under obj and a csproj file with the extension I would need locally:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <WarningsAsErrors></WarningsAsErrors>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>**</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When I try to run this locally with mvn azure-functions:run the function works locally but when I hit the URLof my endpoint I get the same error: Unable to resolve the value for property 'CosmosDBAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting'. Trying to mvn package with a local.setting.json file however will give me a different error and complains about no functions found and that I should have added them in a configuration file... This is probably a different branch to investigate so except if it rings a bell I wouldn't go there for now.

I don't have a local.setting.json file, I'm deploying the project via a release pipeline as a folder and not as a zip or war file, my ConnectionStringSetting in the function is hardcoded for now in a final static variable and the CosmosDBAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting is added in the application settings with all permutations that came to my mind. Could you tell me if you see something wrong that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the Azure Functions docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-trigger?tabs=csharp#configuration), the content of the `connectionStringSetting` in the Json should be the **name of the setting, not the connection string itself**. I am not super familiar with Java but normally, both the Json and the Function signature point to the same value (the name of the configuration, not the value).

[image: Snippet of configuration documentation]

```
"connectionStringSetting" : "THE_SETTING_NAME",
```

```
@CosmosDBInput(name = "name",
                    databaseName = "myproject-db",
                    collectionName = "ObjectToReturn",
                    id = "{Query.id}",
                    partitionKey = "{Query.id}",
                    connectionStringSetting =  "THE_SETTING_NAME")
```

Then you go to your Function App in Azure and create an [Application Setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal) with that same name and the value will be the actual connection string.

When working locally, you have your `local.settings.json` which would have the name of the property with the actual value.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. That the error was CosmosDBAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting missing and not a chunk of my string was very confusing and prone to mistakes. I can advance at last...

Comment: I would have expected an error like "variable AccountEndpoint=https://" contains invalid characters or so, but instead it would complain about a fixed var name, in this case ConnectionStringSetting, like if I had defined which is not the case